# SQLite complains about null values in a column lacking a NOT NULL constraint

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft.data.sqlite

I'm getting a curious error when inserting a record into a SQLite table.
This is from the logs of a customer:

```rb
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Events.details'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SqliteDemo.LogEvent(...) in ...
```

The pertinent bit of diagnostics is obviously this:

```
SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Events.details'
```

…which seems clear enough, except for one thing: The `details` column lacks a `NOT NULL` constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Events (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name STRING NOT NULL,
    time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    code INTEGER NOT NULL,
    details STRING,
    message STRING NOT NULL,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL )
```

I don't know the values that failed to insert, so an obvious next step would be to improve my diagnostics and wait for it to happen again. Or I could just add null guards to
make sure it never happens again and forget about the whole thing.

But I'm curious:

- Is it possible that SQLite's diagnostics are in error, and that it is one of the
  `NOT NULL` columns that is the actual culprit?
- Why don't my unit tests have a problem with null `detail` values?
- Can this be related to SQLite's dynamic approach to typing?
- …or something completely different?

Any ideas?

#### Environment

- Targeting .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 10
- Using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` 5.0.14 
  (not `System.Data.SQLite` – though I'm unsure whether the distinction is relevant).

#### Code

I can't post our production code here.
Instead, here is a complete, stand-alone C# program that I believe closely parallels the production code in all pertinent aspects.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

class SqliteDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqliteDemo demo = new SqliteDemo();
        demo.LogEvent("name 1", DateTime.Now, 42, "details", "message 1", 0);
        demo.LogEvent("name 2", DateTime.Now, 42, null, "message 2", 0); //*** Works...
    }

    readonly string connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = "Test.db",
        Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
    }.ConnectionString;

    const string CreateTableSql =
        @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Events (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name STRING NOT NULL,
            time INTEGER NOT NULL,
            code INTEGER NOT NULL,
            details STRING,
            message STRING NOT NULL,
            status INTEGER NOT NULL
        )";

    int LogEvent(string name, DateTime time,
            int code, string details, string message, short status)
    {
        using (SqliteConnection connection = CreateOpenConnection())
        {
            using (SqliteCommand command = CreateCommand(connection,
                "INSERT INTO Events(name, time, code, details, message, status) " +
                "VALUES(@name, @time, @code, @details, @message, @status)"))
            {
                AddParameter(command, "name", name);
                AddParameter(command, "time", time);
                AddParameter(command, "code", code);
                AddParameter(command, "details", details);
                AddParameter(command, "message", message);
                AddParameter(command, "status", status);

                return command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //*** SOMETIMES throws
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddParameter(SqliteCommand command, string name, object value)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter(name, value ?? DBNull.Value));
    }

    static SqliteCommand CreateCommand(SqliteConnection connection, string sql)
    {
        SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        return command;
    }

    SqliteConnection CreateOpenConnection()
    {
        SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        CreateTableIfNecessary(connection);
        return connection;
    }

    void CreateTableIfNecessary(SqliteConnection connection)
    {
        using (SqliteCommand command = CreateCommand(connection, CreateTableSql))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exact build of SQLite?

Comment: I assume you mean the C libraries? Hang on, and I'll dig it out...

Comment: `e_sqlite3.dll` does not have much in the way of metadata. I can say that the x64 version was last modified 17.08.2020 16:38 and is 1,570,816 bytes...

Comment: Sounds like 3.33.0. There are no official bug fixed but maybe a newer version would give different results. Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: No triggers. The `CreateTableSql` string is all there is. The table is typically quite small (less than 1,000 rows) and everything works fine for the most part. Except for the occasional complaint about the `NOT NULL` **details** column.

Comment: (And while I know how to make it stop, I would dearly like to know what this is all about.)

Comment: Btw, it doesn't impact your question, I don't think, but SQLite doesn't have an affinity of "STRING" type, but does alias "STRING" to a numeric affinity, which can lead to some odd surprises in edge cases.  In other words, using STRING for a column type in SQLite is almost always a problem.

Comment: Execute `select * from pragma_table_info('Events');` to check the nulability of the column.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like you are passing `message` to your procedure, and in one case its value is `null`. But in a `create table` script you have a constraint `message STRING NOT NULL` which throws an error on insert (as `null` is not allowed to `message` column). Try to put `empty string` instead of `null` and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: My bad -- I passed a null message just to verify that I **did** get the expected error in that case...and forgot to change it back. Fixed now.

Comment: I mean, the `message` column **does** have a **NOT NULL** constraint, so there the exception is expected. Not so the `details` column...

Comment: So, have you received 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Events.details' when you pass a `null` to `message` field? (or Events.message)

Comment: When I passed `null` to `message` I got an error about `Events.message`, not `Events.details`. (This was expected, to be sure.)

Comment: Did you try to check if your production table really allows null to details? CreateTableIfNecessary creates table only if not exists in database. There could be a case when someone has created table with `NOT NULL` constraints, after that change the script of `details` to allow `null`, but the table wasn't dropped and recreated with new constraint

Comment: The possibility occurred to me, but I don't think so. The database has only the one table, and after doing a bit of GIT archeology I'm pretty sure that column never had a null constraint.

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-describe-table/

Maybe you could do some investigation of that using this article?